# SqlDataSource SelectCommand contains null values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

My SQL code that works running on the server.

```
SELECT 
    [LINE_NO], [CUST_ORDER_ID], [PART_ID], 
    [CUSTOMER_PART_ID], [MISC_REFERENCE], [PROMISE_DATE], 
    [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] 
FROM 
    [CUST_ORDER_LINE] 
WHERE 
    ([CUST_ORDER_ID] = '33742-1' 
     AND [PROMISE_DATE] IS NULL
     AND [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] IS NULL)
```

My asp.net code.

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT [LINE_NO], [CUST_ORDER_ID], [PART_ID], [CUSTOMER_PART_ID], [MISC_REFERENCE], [PROMISE_DATE], [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] FROM [CUST_ORDER_LINE] WHERE ([CUST_ORDER_ID] = ? AND [PROMISE_DATE] = ? AND [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] = ?)"
```

I'm using 3 query string parameters. The promise date and promise delivery date can be null. But when those values are null it returns no records.

How can I program this to change the SQL to `'is null'` instead of `= ''`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

- Param 1 = OrderID
- Param 2/3 are both Promise Date
- Param 4/5 are both Promise Delivery Date

Code:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT [LINE_NO], [CUST_ORDER_ID], [PART_ID], [CUSTOMER_PART_ID], [MISC_REFERENCE], [PROMISE_DATE], [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] FROM [CUST_ORDER_LINE] WHERE [CUST_ORDER_ID] = ? AND (? IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DATE] = ?) AND (? IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] = ?)"
```

The SQL would be:

```
DECLARE @P1 INT, @P2 DATETIME, @P3 DATETIME

SELECT [LINE_NO], [CUST_ORDER_ID], [PART_ID], [CUSTOMER_PART_ID], [MISC_REFERENCE], [PROMISE_DATE], [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] 
FROM [CUST_ORDER_LINE] 
WHERE [CUST_ORDER_ID] = @P1 
AND (@P2 IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DATE] = @P2)
AND (@P3 IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] = @P3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works great.  I'm new to asp.net so I didn't make the connection between the extra parameters.  Technically speaking the SQL would be AND (@P2 IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DATE] = @P3)
AND (@P4 IS NULL OR [PROMISE_DEL_DATE] = @P5)